# Bind events to mvvm model in Windows 8

Tags: webview, windows-8, mvvm-light

I want to bind event in WebView, but i am having exception:

> An exception of type '`Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException`'
>   occurred in VK.exe but was not handled in user code
>
> WinRT information: Cannot add instance of type
>   '`Win8nl.Behaviors.EventToCommandBehavior`' to a collection of type
>   '`System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<WinRtBehaviors.Behavior>`'

As you probably know, with Windows SDK **there is no System.Interaction.dll**. I was trying to find it on the web (compiled for Windows RT) or in Blend folder but could not.

Than i found **[Win8nl](http://nuget.org/packages/Win8nl)** that uses Behaviors to allow me to connect events of controls and RelayCommands in viewmodel.

They helps me to bind loaded event for view:
Here is code:

```
...
xmlns:WinRtBehaviors="using:WinRtBehaviors"
xmlns:Win8nl_Behavior="using:Win8nl.Behaviors"
DataContext="{Binding Login, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

<WebView x:Name="webView" 
    Grid.Row="1"                 
    Grid.Column="1"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
    Height="420" Width="530">
    <WinRtBehaviors:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Win8nl_Behavior:EventToCommandBehavior Event="LoadCompleted"       
                                            Command="WebViewLoadedCommand" />
        </WinRtBehaviors:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </WebView>
```

ViewModel:

```
public LoginViewModel(IDataService dataService)
{
    WebViewLoadedCommand = new RelayCommand(() => {
    var msg = new MessageDialog("Web View Loaded");

    msg.ShowAsync();
    });
}

public RelayCommand WebViewLoadedCommand { get; private set; }
```

Also i want to get NavigatedEventsArgs parameter, like i was doing for WP7 & System.Interaction:

```
 <i:Interaction.Triggers>
     <i:EventTrigger EventName="Navigated">
         <mvvm:EventToCommand Command="{Binding NavigatedCommand, Mode=OneWay}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
      </i:EventTrigger>
 </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you want [WinRt Triggers](http://winrttriggers.codeplex.com/).

This open source project implements Interaction.Triggers for WinRT